# how to authenticate to external rest url in web api

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on rest Services which is a external travel portal api which talks in json format.
I want to create an action method to post username and password to this api url.
I am able to do it in fiddler but dont know how to transmit information in web api action method.this url will return back a token id which i will be used for all sub request.
My questions--

I am passing username and password from view page to controller through formCollection. I want to know how to add jsonArray with credentials to this request headers and get back the response back.

```
     [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult About(FormCollection form)
    {
        string url = "http://someurl.com//api/PersonalDetails/GetPersonalDetails";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
                        Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
```

The json array is something like this:

```
    {
     "ClientId": "ApiIntegration",
     "UserName": "xxxxxx",
     "Password": "xxxxxx@12",
     "EndUserIp": "192.168.11.120"
     }
```

I want to send this array with parameters to this url. but dont know how to do it.
I was trying to create anonymous method and pass value to request headers.
Trying something like this:

```
      var arr = new
        {
            ClientId = "ApiIntegration",
            UserName = Convert.ToString(form["UserName"].ToString()),
            Password = Convert.ToString(form["Password"].ToString()),
            EndUserIp = "192.168.11.120"
        };
```

**In fiddler,it was very simple. i have simply put all credentials in Response body and in Request Headers, set the Content-Type to application/json and get back all the data**.

Please help me someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to post data to this endpoint:

```
string url = "http://someurl.com//api/PersonalDetails/GetPersonalDetails";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        ClientId = "ApiIntegration",
        UserName = Convert.ToString(form["UserName"].ToString()),
        Password = Convert.ToString(form["Password"].ToString()),
        EndUserIp = "192.168.11.120"
    });

    var response =  await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // deserialize the json and get your token id
}
```

Comment: Thnks for your help i will try it

Comment: one more ques, the generated token id is used for all subsequent request so whether web api support session or i should use caching to store token id??

Comment: That is an answer for a different question :) I would probably stick it in some distributed cache though.